# Namespacing animations

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to namespace animations? Specifically, my problem is that on a given element `$myElement` I am doing animations of two types. Now I would like to use `.stop()` on only one of these types, not both.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Code available here: http://jsfiddle.net/y34ME/1/

My problem is that when I click the `span` I want it to fade away, regardless of whether I do a `mouseout`. Currently, the `mouseout` interrupts the fading away because of the `.stop()`, but I need the `.stop()` to prevent `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to queue up.

Comment: You can use two different queues. How about showing some actual code?

Comment: @all: I've added a fiddle, and an explanation.

Comment: You can't send reply notifications to everybody on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you really want is to not trigger the mouseout at all if you're already fading the element away. Andrew's method works well, but if you want to keep your event handlers intact (for example, if there's a way to show this element again), use a state class:

```
$('p').delegate('span:not(.hidden)', {
    'mouseover': function () {
       $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'blue'}, 1000);
    },
    'mouseout':function () {
       $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 1000);
    },
    'click': function () {
       $(this).addClass('hidden').stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'green'}, 1000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y34ME/4/

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you need to use delegate?  This code seems to do what you want:

```
$("span").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "blue"}, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "white"}, 1000);
    }
);

$("span").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "green"}, 1000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I want to use `.delegate()` to limit the number of event handlers are defined, for performance reasons

Answer (score 2):

Just use undelegate. For cleaner code it can all be encapsulated in one delegate call also.

```
  $('p').delegate('span',{
                'mouseover':function(e){  
       $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'blue'}, 1000);
                 },
                'mouseout':function(e){
       $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 1000);
                },
                'click':function(e){
       $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'green'}, 1000).fadeTo(2000, 0).undelegate( 'mouseout' );
                }

                });
```

Comment: Undelegate is too strong! I don't want to undelegate all `span`s, just this one.

Comment: give it a class then and create a condition around just that span